# Redis Client del function not being called inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I have been trying to call the redisClient.del function inside a for loop and the function is not returning any state.

```
studentSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function () {
    let admin = this;
    let access = 'student';
    let token = jwt.sign({ _id: student._id.toHexString(), access }, HRCSECRET).toString();
    student.tokens.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element.token);
        redisClient.del(element.token, (err, result) => {
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            else{
                console.log(result);
            }
        })
    });
    student.tokens = [{ access, token }];
    return student.save().then(() => { return token; });
};
```

There is no console.log statement printed during the execution

Comment: What is `student.tokens` ? Are you sure that it contains something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to check in Redis-cli is your stuff deleted?

Just a little refactor below

```
studentSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = async () => {
  // your code before
  const promises = []  
  student.tokens.forEach(element => {
    promises.push(redisClient.del(element.token))
  })
  await Promise.all(promises)
  // your next code
}
```

Comment: appearently the Exact thing happened